# Get index pairs of sublists from a list of integers

Tags: scala

Using Scala, how to get a list of tuples containing starting and ending indexes of sublists within another list of integers?

Consider this list:

```
val xs = List(3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5)
```

There are two sublists that begin and end with the same number, and have smaller numbers in between - `3, 1, 1, 3` and `5, 4, 4, 5`.

I would like to collect the starting and ending indexes of those sublists in a list of tuples. Based on the above example, this list would be:

```
List[(Int, Int)]((0, 3), (4, 7))
```

.. because the first subset begins at index 0 and ends at 3 and the second one has indexes of 4 and 7.

What would be an elegant Scala function that does this?

Edit: I know the imperative way to do this with `var`s and for-loops. I am interested in finding an elegant functional solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "one-liner" solution:

```
xs.zipWithIndex
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).combinations(2).map(c => (c(0), c(1))).toList)
  .toList
  .flatMap { case (x, intervals) => 
    intervals.filter{ case (a, b) => xs.slice(a, b).exists(_ < x)}
  }
```

produces:

```
List((4,7), (0,3))
```

A hopefully slightly more readable version with meaningfully named intermediate results:

```
val numbersToIndices = xs.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
val groupedIntervalsAsLists = numbersToIndices.mapValues(_.combinations(2).toList)
val groupedIntervals = intervalsAsLists.mapValues(_.map(v => (v(0), v(1)))).toList
val valleys = for {
  (x, intervals) <- groupedIntervals
  (a, b) <- intervals
  if xs.slice(a, b).exists(_ < x)
} yield (a, b)

println(valleys)
```

again finds

```
List((4,7), (0,3))
```

Comment: The one-liner still returns (0,3) for `xs = List(3, 1, 4, 3, 8, 7,4,2, 4,7, 8)`; I think it shouldn't.

Comment: @jrook Maybe the last intermediate result name `valleys` is unfortunate... It doesn't select "strict valleys", it selects all intervals that *"have smaller numbers in between"*. I'm not sure how the *"have smaller numbers in between"* should be interpreted, I've interpreted it as `exists`, but it should be trivial to replace it by any other condition.

Answer (score 0):

What about this implementation?

```
xs.foldLeft[((Int, Int), Option[Int], List[(Int, Int)])]((0, 0), None, Nil) {
  case ((window, boundOption, result), value) =>
    boundOption match {
      case Some(bound) =>
        if (bound != value)
          ((window._1, window._2 + 1), Some(bound), result)
        else
          ((window._2 + 1, window._2 + 1), None, window :: result)
      case None => ((window._1, window._2 + 1), Some(value), result)
    }
}._3.reverse
```

Comment: This produces a slightly inaccurate result:

`xs: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3)`

`res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,4), (5,6), (7,8))`

Comment: Sorry I missed the condition where bound have to *have smaller numbers in between*, which would be the expected solution for the example that you have added in the previous comment?